# Why Susy gives 49.15254% in output CSS instead of 50%?

Tags: css, grid, sass, frontend, susy-compass

I've made decision to get started with **Susy**, because I wanted good framework just for **grids**. Unfortunately I found myself trying hard to make exact what I want. After all I want to know why Susy gives so strange math rules.

There are my Susy's simple setings:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    math: fluid,
    output: float,
    gutter-override: no-gutters,    
);
```

As you can see, I removed gutters as above (don't know if it's best way to do this eg. I've noticed someone using `gutters: 0` or even `gutters: null` ).

**Finally, I found solution for strange 49.15254%:**

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    math: fluid,
    output: float,
    gutter-override: no-gutters,
    gutter-position: inside,
);
```

Can someone explain me why Susy made any gutters (or smth), even when `gutter-override: no-gutters` was given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `gutter-override` is to change the gutter output without changing the underlying math of the grid. All `no-gutters` does is turn off the gutter output. It's not meant to be used globally, like that. To actually change the grid math, you need to set `gutters: 0`.

When you use `gutter-position` inside, you make it so the grid math is the same either way — because the size of the gutters doesn't effect the size of the columns.

Comment: Thanks! :) I was confused.